Blue Wire in USB OTG
I am trying to make a otg usb cable. I have researched the issue and  have seen how to wire cords with four wires. But the usb c cable that I have has wires. Red,white, green, blue, black. Plus, filter wire. I would like to know what is the blue wire and what to do with it in making otg cable. Thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

We literally cannot know what kind of OTG cable you are talking about and trying to construct. And the wire colours can be random anyway. If you are in a situation that you need a custom USB cable you cannot buy from a store, you likely are doing something that can't be achieved or then one of the devices is designed incorrectly with wrong connector. What kind of OTG cable you are trying to do and why? Also do you mean shield by saying filter?

Sorry for lake of info. The usb cable is usb-c. I'm trying to convert it in an otg host cable. Usually there are four wires . But mine has five. Red blue white green black, and yes a shield wire. I can't seem to upload a photo of it. I know with microusb the five pin is grounded. But I do not know what the blue wire is on this usb type c cord. Or how to wire it into an otg cable, since it has a shield wire attached.

I have done more research. Can this be layout of the wires. Red- vbus, blue-cc,white- D+, green-D-, black-ground,and shield.

@Sammyb But we have no clue what you call an "OTG" cable and how exactly you have planned to make an OTG cable from a Type-C cable that is cut into half. What will be in the other end, and what do you intend to connect with such an "OTG" cable that you are unable to buy from shops? Generally Type-C cables has no concept of OTG. The colours may or might not be what you describe, you cannot count on it without double-checking yourself how the colors map to your pins.

The cord is a Samsung USB data cable. And I was planning to connect a microusb male to the other end. So that my phone would be host to the connected device.  And the cable has these colored wires as I've shown above.
